# Porque no se hace el bucle que quiero

Tags: javascript

Me ocurre lo siguiente. Yo lo que quiero es que se cree un bucle si el cliente no pone lo que el prompt especifica.

[image: Esa seria el prompt]

[image: Esto ocurre cuando escribo "si" o "no" o cuando escribo cualquier cosa]

El codigo seria el siguiente:

```js
let envio = prompt(" ¿Lo retiras en tienda? Habra una suma de 210$ si lo llevamos a su domicilio (Si/No) ")
do {
    envio
    if(envio == "Si" || envio =="si" || envio == "SI" ){
        total = total
    }else
        total = total + 210
        for (const producto of productos) {
            producto.enviar()
        }
} while (envio != "Si" || envio !="si" || envio != "SI" || envio != "no" || envio != "NO" || envio != "No"){
    alert("no pusiste lo especificado")
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si le cancela debería seguir preguntando?

Comment: la idea es que ponga solamente si o no

Comment: si pone no, deberia saltar a otra pregunta

Comment: ¿Y si simplemente no quiere responder? ¿No crees que sería buena idea tener una elección por defecto?

Comment: y cual sería la otra pregunta?

Comment: Desde el punto de vista de experiencia de usuario (UX) un proceso tan bloqueante no es muy adecuado. Al menos una cantidad de intentos deberías permitir, cumplidos los mismos, salir del bucle y redirigir sería lo suyo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo así

```
function mostrarPrompt() {
  let mensaje = '¿Lo retiras en tienda? Habra una suma de 210$ si lo llevamos a su domicilio (Si/No)'
  let posiblesRespuestas = ['si', 'no']

  let respuesta = prompt(mensaje)
  respuesta = respuesta.trim().toLowerCase()

  if (posiblesRespuestas.includes(respuesta)) {
    if (respuesta == 'si') {
         // aqui pones lo que tenga que hacer si te responde que si
    } else {
         // aqui lo que sucede si pone no
    }
    

    return;
  }

  mostrarPrompt()
}
```

En esta parte checamos que la respuesta del cliente este dentro de las respuestas admitidas

```
if (posiblesRespuestas.includes(respuesta.trim().toLowerCase())) {
```

a su respuesta le aplicamos un trim() para eliminar posibles espacios en blanco
y también un toLowerCase para poner todo en minúscula

Si el usuario puso una respuesta valida entra dentro del if y hace tu for y el return termina la ejecución de la función

Si no dio una respuesta válida no entra en el if y vuelve a llamar a la función y esta llama al prompt de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Volví a reestructurar tu código, aquí puse el `alert` dentro del `do-while`, así sucedería que cada vez que no se cumpla el ciclo (o sea si decimos cualquier cosa diferente a `si` o `no`), vuelve a repetir la pregunta (o sea, muestra el `alert`), hasta romper el ciclo:

```js
let total = 0;
let envio;

do {
    envio = prompt(" ¿Lo retiras en tienda? Habra una suma de 210$ si lo llevamos a su domicilio (Si/No) ");
    if (envio != "Si" && envio != "si" && envio != "SI" && envio != "no" && envio != "NO" && envio != "No") {
        alert("no pusiste lo especificado");
    }else{
        if (envio == "Si" || envio == "si" || envio == "SI") {
            total = total;
        } else {
            total = total + 210;
            for (const producto of productos) {
                producto.enviar();
            }
        }
    }
} while (envio != "Si" && envio != "si" && envio != "SI" && envio != "no" && envio != "NO" && envio != "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

El bucle no funciona como esperarías porque la pregunta está fuera de él.

Además la operación en la condición debería ser **y** (`&&`), no **o** (`||`).

Ya que la variable no puede tomar más de un valor al mismo tiempo. Entonces cuando se ingresa una respuesta esperada, el ciclo sigue ejecutándose porque hay una parte de la condición que sí es válida.

Para que se ejecute nuevamente debes hacerlo así:

```js
let envio, total;
do {
    envio = prompt(" ¿Lo retiras en tienda? Habra una suma de 210$ si lo llevamos a su domicilio (Si/No) ")
    envio = envio?.toLowerCase()
    if(envio == "si"){
        // ...
    }else
        total = total + 210
        // ...
} while (envio != "si" && envio != "no"){
    alert("no pusiste lo especificado")
}
```

Por cierto, propongo que lo hagas así:

```js
function preguntar(){
    let resultado = prompt(" ¿Lo retiras en tienda? Habra una suma de 210$ si lo llevamos a su domicilio (Si/No) ")
    return resultado?.toLowerCase()
}

function insistirPregunta(){
    let resultado = preguntar()
    while (resultado != "si" && resultado != "no"){
        alert("no pusiste lo especificado")
        resultado = preguntar()
    }
    return resultado
}

function enviarProductos() {
    // ...
}

envio = insistirPregunta()

if(envio == "no") 
    total = total + 210

enviarProductos()
```